# Two men and a boy started their journey - Help them to know each other

Tags: riddle

> 2 Men and a boy started a **never-ending race**. One of the men can run super fast while the other can run faster than the boy. The boy is the slowest runner. **What are they?**

(This puzzle is taken from my website. There's a link in my profile.)

Comment: are you an analog wrist watch?

Comment: Curious out of all the things for the analogy, why 2 men and a boy =)

Answer (score 3):

They are

> the hands of a clock

Because

> there are two long hands, the minute hand and the second hand, which represent the men, because one moves one second at a time and the other one moves one minute at a time.

And

> The kid is the short hand, the hour hand, which moves one hour at a time.

Comment: Edited! For future reference: click the 'edit' button (underneath the main body of the answer) to see the formatting for spoilers.

Comment: I would argue that I'm even faster than your _super fast_ runner.

Comment: It depends on how big the c**** is